# Twitter bootstrap modal boxes, margins behaving differently on different dev boxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, modal-dialog

I have this twitter bootbox modal that comes up on the screen with the default margin type:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

I have this jquery code that I kick to adjust the default top margin so it doesn't "float" down so far:

```
        $("#myModal").modal({ // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
            "backdrop": "static",
            "keyboard": true,
            "show": false // ensure the modal is not shown immediately
        }).css({
                    'width': function () {
                        return ($(document).width() * .95) + 'px';
                        //return $(document).width() + 'px';
                    },
                    'margin-left': function () {
                        return -($(this).width() / 2);
                    }
                    ,'margin-top': function () {
                        return -$(this).height() * 1.20;
                    }
                });
```

the html def is here:

```
  <div id="myModal"
     class="modal hide fade"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="label1"
     aria-hidden="true"
     data-backdrop="static"
     data-keyboard="false"
     data-show="false">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="label1">Label</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 580px;">
    <table id="main_table" class="table table-striped">
      <tr>          
        <th width="">Reserved By</th>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a style="width: 93%;" class="brand pull-left toggle_drop_down" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emp-list">
          Click here to search for employees not in your list
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn pull-right down_chevron" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emp-list">
          <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-black"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn pull-right up_chevron" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emp-list" style="display:none;">
          <i class="icon-chevron-up icon-black"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="emp-list" class="collapse out">

      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
             id="employee_list"
             class="display table table-striped"
             data-source="<%= home_url(format: "json") %>">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="modal-footer">-->
  <!--<a href="#" class="btn primary">Close</a></div>-->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

this bit of code looks great on my machine but deploying to our development server or other users boxes it does not work at all... like it doesn't float down far.  I am not sure why its different, the other developers machines run the same windows/chrome/rubymine/rails server and rails version.  I am just here grabbing at straws trying to discover why there is a discrepency.

(the dev server we deploy too is a linux box but still hittting it on chrome it doesn't look the same as when i hit my localhost:3000)

Answer (score 0):

found a better way to do it by dynamically using the height:

```
       $("#myModal .modal-body").css({
                'max-height':function () {
                    var h =  $(window).height()-250;
                    //alert(h); let me know what the windows are reporting
                    return (h);
                }


        });
```